# Unitary operator that leaves a dense subspace invariant

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, $\mathcal{D}$ be a dense subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ and $U$ be an unitary operator on $\mathcal{H}$.

Suppose that $U\mathcal{D}\subseteq \mathcal{D}$. Can we say that $U\mathcal{D}= \mathcal{D}$?
If this is not true, do you know a counter example?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that base is $\{e_n, n \in\mathbb{Z}\}$ consider the shift operator $S(e_n)=e_{n+1}$ and $D=\{x=(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ with $x_i\neq 0, i<0$. $S(D)\subset D$, but $x=(x_n)$ with $x_n=1/n, i\neq 0, x_0=0$ is not in $S(D)$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I meant a dense 'subspace' $\mathcal{D}$ but I wrote only subset. I edit.

Comment: Sorry, shift operator is not unitary.

Comment: The shift is unitary on a basis indexed by the integers. You're probably thinking of the unilateral shift on a basis indexed by the naturals.